# Question from the Brazilian Math Olympiad

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, contest-math

I am stuck with this problem that appeared in the Undergrad Brazilian Math Olympiad from 2017. The problem is:

> let $x_n$ be a strictly positive sequence that $x_n\rightarrow 0$.
> Suppose that exists $c>0$ that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq c x_n ^2$ for all
> $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that there is $d>0$ that $n x_n\geq d$ for all
> $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I tried using the Stolz-Cesàro lemma, but didn't help me very much. Does anyone have a hint? Thanks!

EDIT:

Let me give some context of my idea. For the Stolz-Cesàro lemma the given sequence $x_n$ needs to be strictly decreasing, since it $x_n\rightarrow 0$ and $x_n>0$. Well, I don't know if that is true, the best thing I've got was: given $\varepsilon>0$ it is true that $(1-\varepsilon)a_n<a_{n+1}<(1+\varepsilon)a_n$ for sufficiently large $n$. One could help me on that.

Moreover, the lemma says that for $|b_n|\rightarrow \infty$ if
$$\displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}\rightarrow \ell$$ then
$\displaystyle \frac{a_n}{b_n}\rightarrow \ell.$

Supposing that $x_n$ is strictly decreasing, than I can choose $a_n=n$ and $b_n=1/x_n$. That way I would have
$$c_n=\frac{(n+1)-n}{\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{x_{n}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{x_{n}}}.$$
If it is possible to show that this sequence $c_n$ converges to some positive number I would have the result.

But with these assumptions (including that $x_n$ is strictly decreasing) the best thing that I've got was:
$$\frac{1}{c}(1-x_n)\leq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{x_{n}}}=\frac{x_{n+1}x_n}{x_n-x_{n+1}}.$$

At this point there are two things that I don't know: (1) $x_n$ strictly decreases and (2) how do I find a comparison (if there is any) to show that $\displaystyle \frac{x_{n+1}x_n}{x_n-x_{n+1}}< d_n$, where $d_n\rightarrow 1/c$.

One last thing that I noticed is that the hypothesis $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq c x_n ^2$ implies that $x_{n+1}/x_n\rightarrow 1$  and
$$f_n=\frac{|x_{n+1}-x_n|}{x_n ^2}$$
has a convergent subsequence. These facts implies that
$$\frac{x_{n+1}x_n}{x_n-x_{n+1}}$$ also has a convergent subsequence.

That's it, please help!

Comment: Is [this](http://www.obmep.org.br/) the olympiad page? Don't they publish solutions? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close this question.

Comment: They do publish some of the problems solutions, but this one isn't published.

Comment: @RobertShore I'm guessing because of "shows no effort".  IE It is "missing context and details".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're to show that there exists such $d>0$ that $\frac{1}{nx_n}<\frac{1}{d}$ i.e. that $\frac{1}{nx_n}$ is bounded from above.
Consider $y_n=\frac{1}{cnx_n}$ i.e. $x_n=\frac{1}{cny_n}$ then the inequality $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le cx_n^2$ becomes
$$\left|\frac{1}{c(n+1)y_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{cny_n}\right|\le c\frac{1}{c^2n^2y_n^2}$$
and we can cancel $c$. After some rearrangements the inequality becomes
$$\frac{1}{n y_n - 1} + 1
\ge (n+1)y_{n+1}-ny_n\ge
\frac{1}{1 + n y_n} - 1$$
then, noting $ny_n\to +\infty$ as $ny_n=\frac{1}{cx_n}$ and $x_n\to +0$, we have $\frac{1}{ny_n-1}+1\to 1$ thus LHS is bounded by some constant $C$ from above and we can write
$$C\ge \frac{1}{n y_n - 1} + 1
\ge (n+1)y_{n+1}-ny_n$$
$$C\ge (n+1)y_{n+1}-ny_n$$
summing up for $n=1,\ldots,\,m$ we have
$$Cm\ge (m+1)y_{m+1}-y_1$$
$$C(m+1)\ge Cm\ge (m+1)y_{m+1}-y_1$$
$$C\ge y_{m+1}-\frac{y_1}{m+1}$$
$$y_1+C\ge\frac{y_1}{m+1}+C\ge y_{m+1}$$
i.e. $y_{m+1}$ is bounded from above. QED.

"Some rearrangements":

$$\left|\frac{1}{c(n+1)y_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{cny_n}\right|\le c\frac{1}{c^2n^2y_n^2}$$
$$-\frac{1}{n^2y_n^2}\le \frac{1}{(n+1)y_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{ny_n}\le \frac{1}{n^2y_n^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{ny_n}-\frac{1}{n^2y_n^2}\le \frac{1}{(n+1)y_{n+1}}\le \frac{1}{ny_n}+\frac{1}{n^2y_n^2}$$
$$\frac{ny_n-1}{n^2y_n^2}\le \frac{1}{(n+1)y_{n+1}}\le \frac{ny_n+1}{n^2y_n^2}$$
Now we consider only that $y_n$ for which $ny_n-1>0$, the other are already bounded from above by $\frac 1n$.
$$\frac{n^2y_n^2}{ny_n-1}\ge (n+1)y_{n+1}\ge \frac{n^2y_n^2}{ny_n+1}$$
$$\frac{n^2y_n^2-ny_n(ny_n-1)}{ny_n-1}\ge (n+1)y_{n+1}-ny_n\ge 
\frac{n^2y_n^2-ny_n(ny_n+1)}{ny_n+1}$$
$$\frac{ny_n}{ny_n-1}\ge (n+1)y_{n+1}-ny_n\ge 
\frac{-ny_n}{ny_n+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.) Spent 3.5 hours so not-a-contest solution) Contests are 4h-6h likely.

Answer (score 1):

[This seems a lot easier than I expected, so there might be errors in it. If so, please let em know where.]

These steps can be demystified by referencing the subsequent block of text

1. Pick $N$ such that $ \forall n > N$, $x_n < \frac{ 1}{2c}$.
2. Set $ k = \min (  \frac{1}{2c}, Nx_N ) $. Observe that $\frac{N}{N+1} \geq \frac{1}{2} \geq ck$ and  $ Nx_N \geq k$.
3. Hence $(N+1) x_{N+1} \geq (N+1)( x_N - cx_N^2) \geq (N+1)(\frac{k}{N} - \frac{ ck^2}{N^2})  = k + \frac{k( \frac{N}{N+1} - ck ) }{N^2(N+1)}  \geq   k$.
4. Also, $ \frac{N+1}{N+1+1} \geq \frac{1}{2} \geq ck$.
5. Proceed by induction to conclude that $ n x_n \geq k$.

---

We claim that under suitable conditions (to be determined), if $ n x_n \geq k$, then $(n+1) x_{n+1} \geq k $. If so, the result follows by induction.

Which conditions make sense?

1. We have $x_{n+1} \in ( x_n - c x_n^2, x_n + cx_n^2) $.
2. We have $ \frac{k}{n} < x_n$.
3. We will likely want $x - c x^2$ to be increasing, which requires $ x_n < \frac{1}{2c}$. This can be satisfied as $ \lim x_n = 0 $.
4. Henceforth, we assume $ \frac{k}{n} < x_n < \frac{1}{2c}$. This necessitates $ 2ck < n$, which can be achieved.
5. Now, $ (n+1) x_{n+1} > (n+1) \left[ x_n - c x_n^2\right] > (n+1) \left[\frac{k}{n} - \frac{ ck^2 } { n^2 }  \right] $. Verify that $ (n+1) \left[\frac{k}{n} - \frac{ ck^2 } { n^2 }  \right]  \geq k \Leftrightarrow \frac{n}{n+1} \geq ck $.

This gives us all of the conditions that we need.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: The parts order from [this revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3763947/2) made more sense for me.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I agree with you. It's the difference between presenting a clean direct solution for the olympiad vs motivating the approach / values chosen. I just started writing stuff down and it follows immediately (which is why I'm questioning if there is an error).